# Overlaping lines issue with LineChart in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

i am having issue when data for two parts is same and lines overlap each other like in following image.for big data its the big problem . Is there anything to handle such situation in MPAndroidChart.

[image]

Comment: Do you just want the orange line on top? If so, you merely need to alter the order of adding the DataSets. Otherwise, your question as it stands is unclear. What is the exact outcome you want?

Comment: @David what i want is if there are overlapping lines there should be some scenario to see both lines

Comment: You can add and remove a DataSet right? If you remove the top one then underneath will become visible. Otherwise what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add transparent colors for dataset. Maybe then you kinda could see that these lines overlap